# Filling in NaN in columns using conditionals does not works

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data, sklearn-pandas, fillna

```py
train[train['OverallQual']==1]['LotFrontage']
Output:375    NaN
       575     50

train[train['OverallQual']==1]['LotFrontage'].fillna(value=train[train['OverallQual']==1]['LotFrontage'].mean(),inplace=True)

train[train['OverallQual']==1]['LotFrontage']  
Output:375    NaN
       575     50
```

Warning appears after the implementation of second statement
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

So, I tried another method of assignment for null values

```py
train[train.iloc[:,17]==1].iloc[:,3] = train[train.iloc[:,17]==1].iloc[:,3].fillna(50,inplace=True)
train[train['OverallQual']==1]['LotFrontage']
Output:375    NaN
       575    50
```

The Output was the same. The null values are not being filled.

Comment: Please don't use links to some images to describe your problem. Links can be broken in the future and then your question is of no more use to others. So provide some code here and describe your problem with a text.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the guide. Will do that

Comment: If this approach is wrong, please provide an alternate method to achieve this task

Comment: There are tools to highlight code. You can start and end a code block with `~~~`.  Make sure to format your question properly, so that it is easy to read and understand your question. StackOverflow supports markdown, so you can look up all commands by a quick web search. People tend to downvote and leave poorly formatted questions. This is bad since it reduces the chances of getting an answer to your problem. Also make sure, that you provide any information necessary to understand your problem. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask